# Combining heads of lists so that you can create a nested list from two sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list such as `list = {1,4,3,4,6,3,1,2,3,4 ... }` and a range, say, `range = Range[20000]`.

I want to obtain the following output:

```
{{0,1}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,6}, ... {nth element of list, nth element of range}}
```

where `n` is basically `Range[Length[list]]`.

The general question here would be how can I create a list from the $a_i$th index of list `a`, the $b_k$th index of list `b` and so on.

I would have tried `MapThread` but I'm trying to use the `Histogram3D` function so I needed this "nice" list.

Comment: Hi, I provided an answer to your question, I'm not quite sure what you mean with the a_i --> b_k list generation. If you have a specific problem with data visualization (e.g. Histogram3D) then you can just ask that question as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do

```
Transpose@{ Range@20000 - 1, yourList }
```

Or more generally if `yourList` is of varying length

```
Transpose@{ Range@First@Dimensions@yourList - 1, yourList }
```

Extracting a part of the list, say from index i to index j can be done with `Part`or `Take`

```
newList = Transpose@{ yourList, Range@First@Dimensions@yourList };
newList[[i;;j]]
(* or *)
Take[newList,{i,j}]
```

Comment: oh. brilliant. thank you ! didn't see that

Comment: eh.. also! what does '@' do exactly? I see @@ and @@@ under apply, but no @. Edit: found it under 'map'

Comment: Thank you! That helps. I was wondering what to do about varying length. Do you need to do Range@First@Demensions@yourList -1 though? because doesn't Range give a list which is the same dimension + 1?
data = {1,2}
Ex. Range[0,Length[data]] --> {0,1,2}

if I was to have 0 be the first number that is.

Comment: I missed the starting with 0 bit. You are correct about just substracting one from Range@... The @ notation is equivalent to f[g[a]] === f@g@a. It's just a convenient shorthand to get rid of all those brackets.

Comment: `@` is not `Map`, `/@` is. `f@x` just means `f[x]` whereas `f/@ {x,y,z}` does the same as `Map[f,{x,y,z}]`, which yields `{f[x],f[y],f[z]}`.

Comment: {,...{nth element of list, nth element of range}}, do you want the nth element of range and list, or the (n-1)th element? Philosophically ponders what the zeroth element of a list might be ;)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `MapIndexed` is the most canonical method:

```
list = {1, 4, 3, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4};

MapIndexed[{#2[[1]] - 1, #} &, list]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}, {5, 3}, {6, 1}, {7, 2}, {8, 3}, {9, 4}}
> ```

However, `Transpose` and `Range` is faster when `list` is a packed array.

Comment: pardon me but ... canonical? What do you mean in that sense?

Comment: @Eiyrioü pardon me if I am abusing terminology.  I mean that `MapIndexed` is the typical, expected, or intended way to accomplish this.  It is the built-in function that does exactly this.

Comment: Interesting I did not know that. Thanks :D. About the terminology I have no clue whether you are or not, I was just wondering if there was some notation/convention I did not know about. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you've just started learning Mathematica, also check out the `Table` function, which has many applications:

```
Table[{i - 1, list[[i]]}, {i, 1, 20}]
```

> ```
>    {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}, ... }
> ```

Comment: This way is slower for the big list.