# Converting two lists into points?

Tags: list-manipulation

Lets consider If I have two lists of equals ranks then can i convert them into points, like:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
b = {z, s, d, f, g, h}
Point[{a, b}]
```

Does not works for my requirement.
is it possible to get points like (1,z), (2,s)... (6,h)?

Comment: Does Transpose[{a, b}] do what you want? Or are you looking for Map[Point, Transpose[{a, b}]]

Comment: Also,  `Thread[{a, b}] `.Possible duplicate of [Combining heads of lists so that you can create a nested list from two sublists](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4013/combining-heads-of-lists-so-that-you-can-create-a-nested-list-from-two-sublists)

Answer (score 4):

you can try this:

```
a={1,2,3,4,5,6};
b={z,s,d,f,g,h};
Point@Transpose[{a,b}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I do not know what you intend to do I can only show you how to obtain what you ask for

```
 a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
 b = {z, s, d, f, g, h};
 c = Partition[Riffle[a, b], 2]
 Thread[Point[c]]
```

If you need a specific point try

```
 Thread[Point[c]][[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} 
b = {z, s, d, f, g, h}
pair = Table[{a[[i]], b[[i]]}, {i, Length[a]}]
Point @@@ pair


Out[8]= {{1, z}, {2, s}, {3, d}, {4, f}, {5, g}, {6, h}}

Out[9]= {Point[1, z], Point[2, s], Point[3, d], Point[4, f], Point[5, g], Point[6, h]}
```

Comment: It should be `Point /@` instead of `Point @@@` because the correct syntax is `Point[{x,y}]` and not `Point[x,y]`.  Side note: `Point[{{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ...}]` is also valid for multiple points (since version 6 I think), and tends to render faster than separate `Point` primitives.